# Does runif (R) ever return 0/1

Tags: r, random-generation, uniform-distribution

The title says it all. Can it happen that runif (with bounds 0 and 1) returns 0 or 1 in R?

Comment: This [answer on Stack Echange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427049/1154578) is detailed enough to make this question a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like you're already aware that drawing a 0 or 1 from the standard uniform distribution is a zero-probability event. Instead, as I understand it your question is specifically about R, and whether `runif` will return 0 or 1 due to the finite numerical precision of your computer. We can read the following from `?runif`:

> runif will not generate either of the extreme values unless max = min
>   or max-min is small compared to min, and in particular not for the
>   default arguments.

So we conclude that drawing from the standard uniform distribution in R using `runif` will never return 0 or 1. You are safe to, for instance, log-transform the result without worrying about whether you will obtain finite values.

Comment: Re your last sentence: most people are perfectly content with finite values; its the other kind that worry them...